# Execute commands within specific time inside a procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table1

    DECLARE @v1 INT = 1
    SELECT @v1  
END
```

If `select * from table1` command takes more than 3 seconds, I want to ignore it and stop the command and move to execute next command in the procedure.

How to handle that? I mean putting specific period for command execution

Comment: You can try SET LOCK_TIMEOUT, if you have execution delay due to locking

Comment: So you want to set a timeout for a specific statement (or a set of statements) inside a stored procedure. Interesting question. I have no idea how to do it and would like to read the answers to it.

Comment: LOCK_TIMEOUT is wrong, select statement can take long time even if no lock timeout, but it is just big table and sql server needs time to fetch data. You can try short LOCK_TIMEOUT on big table. And, unfortunately, the statement blocks, until fetches all, i tried to add raiserror()   with nowait after select to print datediff() before and after long select,  it prints me the same value, as query time. The single way you can get what you want - run query asynchronously and cancel on client after timeout

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `@@LOCK_TIMEOUT` - see: [@@LOCK_TIMEOUT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lock-timeout-transact-sql)

Comment: Instead of take a look at the current value (that is -1) may be it makes sense to SET  LOCK_TIMEOUT to the desired value?